# AssertionError LLama-cpp-python model failed to load

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, large-language-model, llama

Llama-cpp-python gives me Assertion Error even though im using the GGUF Format.

I am trying to run an AI model in python 3.7.2 with llama-cpp-python 0.1.85, everytime I run this my code I get this error:

```
error loading model: MapViewOfFile failed: Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.

llama_load_model_from_file: failed to load model
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 26, in <module>
    n_ctx=N_CTX,
  File "D:\AI 2\Venv\lib\site-packages\llama_cpp\llama.py", line 323, in __init__
    assert self.model is not None
AssertionError
```

I am using the GGUF format, so I don't know what the problem is, it works fine on a second computer but not on my main machine, any help?

Answer (score 1):

**You need `python >= 3.8`**

```
pip install llama-cpp-python
```

https://pypi.org/project/llama-cpp-python/

[image]

Comment: Let me know if you are successful.

Comment: I still get the same error even on python 3..8